# How do I add a .NET Runtime in Edit->Prefrences?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

Ok I am using Windows and have .Net 3.5 and the Mono 2.6 frameworks installed.  I also have installed MonoDevelop and plan on using it. I just need to know if I am setup to use the Mono runtime.

All my projects have build options for Mono/Microsoft.NET 3.5, but in Edit->Prefrences->.NET Runtimes, all I see is Microsoft.NET. How do I add the Mono runtime to this list and make it default? Or do I even need to do this? I would think I would have to since our projects will be run on Linux, but not sure how to 'make sure' I am actually using Mono and not just .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono *should* show up simply by virtue of being installed.  You can try reinstalling Mono to see if that helps.

If not, click the "Add" button on the Edit->Preferences->.Net Runtimes page and choose where you installed Mono to, generally it will be something like:

C:\Program Files\Mono-2.6.1

If you want it to be the default, click "Set as Default" while it's highlighted and it should turn bold, indicating it is now the default.  There is also a combobox on the main MD toolbar if you want a quicker way of switching between runtimes.

Comment: Thanks, that was bugging me. I'll send an email to the MonoDevelop team about the documentation issue, because I searched and searched again, but to no avail at how to do this :/. I thought I had to find a certain file, not a directory or folder. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt HAVE to build using Mono's compiler on Windows to have your code run on Linux.

As per answers on [Performance: Compile in CS, Run in mono on windows and linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283023/performance-compile-in-vs-run-in-mono-on-windows-and-linux), you can compile with any compiler and run with any runtime because the compiled binary is in an [Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)

You just have to be certain that your code, and the libraries that it uses, do not make operating system specific calls, P/Invoke unmanaged DLL's, or make calls to functions that are incomplete in Mono (mind you, these are getting rare)

Comment: Our team has been following the Mono project very carefully so very minimum changes should have to be made in our code and platform specific code is placed into plug-in assemblies that only ever get called on when the underlying platform is detected to use that plug-in. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: +1 Did a little compile test and everything worked except for the SlimDx reference error. But that doesn't matter sense only Windows users will be using Direct3D, therefore .Net and not Mono. Thanks for the tip about shouldn't have to build using Mono's compiler, otherwise would have confused me a bit. ;)